# How to get values from Document References in Flutter Flow?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutterflow

I have 2 collection: films, genres. And in films collection exists genres as list references.

In my app i want get all genres list values from single document in collection films.

Argument 1: list of reference genres from someone film

Argument 2: format separator for list join

Test Function return errors, in build return default values but references not null

**How me get values from this doc refs?**

films collection:
[image: films collection]

genres collection:
[image: genres collection]

in flutter flow:
[image: in flutter flow]

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:timeago/timeago.dart' as timeago;
import '/flutter_flow/lat_lng.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/place.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/uploaded_file.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart';
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

String? joinGenresFromFilm(
  List<DocumentReference>? filmGenresRef,
  String separator,
) {
  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY BELOW THIS LINE

  // get from filmGenresRef document all ru_name fields and join to string
  if (filmGenresRef == null || filmGenresRef.isEmpty) {
    return null;
  }

  List<String> genres = [];
  for (DocumentReference ref in filmGenresRef) {
    ref.get().then((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
        String ruName = data['ru_name'];
        genres.add(ruName);
      }
    });
  }
  return genres.join(separator);

  /// MODIFY CODE ONLY ABOVE THIS LINE
}
```

**UPD:**

i get this error in test function in editor:

```
Compilation error: Info: Compiling with sound null safety
lib/main.dart:23:9:
Error: The method 'get' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
 - 'DocumentReference' is from 'package:dartpad_sample/main.dart' ('lib/main.dart').
    ref.get().then((snapshot) {
```